# How To Set Javascript Cookie From Sever Side Button Click (VB.net)

Tags: javascript, asp.net, vb.net, cookies

**My Problem**: I create a server side cookie with a ASP.NET (VB) button click.  The cookie gets created but bc there has only been a page `PostBack` with the button click, the cookie is not yet recognized by the server side page load code. It will take a page reload (not just a post-back) for the server side cookie to be recognized.

**My Proposed Solution:** Create a client side cookie with JavaScript and a server side cookie with VB.net when the ASP.NET button click.

```
Private Sub btnTest_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnTest.Click
 If lblTest.text = "Yes" then

  '1st create client side JavaScript cookie

  '2nd create server side cookie
  Dim bCookie As New HttpCookie("promo")
  bCookie.Value = "samplerpromobox"
  bCookie.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(7)
  Response.Cookies.Add(bCookie)

 End If
End Sub
```

**Questions:**

1. How do I create the client side JavaScript cookie with an ASP.NET (VB) button click?
2. How do I request the client side cookie from the server side page load on `PostBack`?

All help with this is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up fixing this issue but not by using my proposed solution.  I instead used the page's PreRender instead of the page's Page_Load to test for the existence of the just created cookie.  Apparently the cookies (and some controls) are not immediately available during the the Page_Load but are available (and all controls) during PreRender.